# How to get particular clicked card id and passing that id to the backend API in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component

i have two components DisplayNotes.vue which is responsible for displaying notes on dashboard wthe response is coming from backend(displayed as a cards),And next component is icons.vue(responsible for icons) in this icons when i click on more-icon(3 dots-icon)[[see option img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOrbN.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOrbN.png) it should open dropdown options,if i click on DeleteNote option i want to get that particular clicked card id based on that id i have to pass that id to my API-url, i am trying to do by using props but it's not hitting proper URl (id is something diff like #7%..)[[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXOOd.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXOOd.png).i am unable to figure out where did i mistake ,please help me to fix this issue

`user.js`

```
   userTrashNote(data){
        return axios.userTrash(`/deleteNote/${data.id}`,data);
    }
```

`icons.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="footer">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
    <i clss="fas fa-image"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <i @click="myFunction();" class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
        <div ref="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <!-- when user click on DeleteNote i have to get that cardid -->
            <a  @click="handlesubmit();">DeleteNote</a>
            <a >ChangeLabel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    props: ['cardId'],
   data() {
        return {
           clickedCard: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        myFunction(event) {
            this.$refs.myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
            return event;
            // document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        },
         async handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                id: this.cardId,
            }
            service.userTrashNote(userData).then(response => {
                console.log("details",this.cardId);
                alert("Note deleted  successfully");
                return response;
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.footer i {
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
}
.footer .fa-bell {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.footer .fa-user {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.footer .fa-palette {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.footer .fa-image {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.footer .fa-archive {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.footer .fa-ellipsis-v {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}
.dropdown {

    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown a{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown-content {
    margin-left: 40%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(241, 234, 234)
}
.show {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

`DisplayNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id" id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle(note.id)" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" :cardId="clickedCard" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes :cardId="clickedCard" :cardContent="cardContent" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,
        UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
            clickedCard: '',
            cardContent: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(id) {
            var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');
            this.clickedCard = id;
            // this.card.content = this.notes.filter((note) => note.id === id);
            var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');
        },
        
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/styles/DisplayNotes.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: Please see the documentation on using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 3):

```
 userTrashNote(data){
        return axios.userTrash("/deleteNote/${data.id}",data);
    }
```

This is wrong, use back ticks

```
userTrashNote(data){
    return axios.userTrash(`/deleteNote/${data.id}`,data);
}
```

Ok so now thats out of the way, Why are you changing the card id on focus? either create a new component and pass it the `note` so it can handle itself or pass the id on delete.

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id" id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle(note.id)" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" :cardId="note.id" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes :cardId="clickedCard" :cardContent="cardContent" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

See how ive now passed `<icons class="imported-icons note-icons" :cardId="note.id" />` the note.id instead of relying on a method to set it.

Comment: Hello @Michael Mano, i changed that thing to backtick, still it's not hitting correct url,                      Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/deleteNote/    [it's not taking any id]

Comment: Hai @Michael Mano, i think i made a mistake on getting cardId,but  i am too much confusing how to fix this issue ,please help me

Comment: Even After changing double quotes to backtick ,the id is not passed to the url

Comment: @Sravani when you are looping over objects in an array that you wish to handle data with you should really use another component, create a card and pass it the card object and let it handle the click. dont change the selected card on each click.

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael Mano, it's working super fine,The way u are explaining is too cool